# How to Update a Component without refreshing full page/ Angular

Tags: angular

I am working on a project in which I want to show the list of events and a can get all events , events by week by month (filtered by date)... How can I change the content of the page as I click on Events by week button for example without refreshing the whole page.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFBPL.png)

Comment: You could create a subject and display it in your component. It will listen to your updates and keep updating the value

Answer (score 0):

add a (click) event to the 'week' button and make the function do the filtering and do something like: this.events = filteredEvents. Does that make any sense?

Comment: yeah, thank you for the idea it works perfectly when just add this to the button: (click)="loadByWeek()" this is a function I defined in the componrnt.ts.